# ML Datasets for Telecommunications Networking

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, dataset, weka

I am working on a **telecommunications networking** project and I am interested in datasets which contains the following features:

- source/destination IP
- packet size.
- protocol.
- Port number.

I have been searching also in UCI datasets but I didn't find anything related to my case study, any advise?